# How can I access form.aspx from codefile.aspx.vb?

Tags: vb.net, forms, code-behind

I have a formview on a page called form.aspx and it of course has a code-behind page called form.aspx.vb

The form.aspx.vb file is huge! So I'd like to take the functions out of the form.aspx.vb page and into functions.vb.

My problems is everything goes out of scope.

example....

form.aspx.vb has this...

```
dim box1, box2, box3 as Textbox

Public Sub initialiseControls()
   box1 = Me.Formview1.FindControl("box1")
   box2 = Me.Formview1.FindControl("box2")
   box3 = Me.Formview1.FindControl("box3")
End Sub
```

I'd like to take this sub and put it into functions.vb codefile, but everything is out of scope then.

Can someone tell me if this can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1) Pass a reference to the Page into every method that needs to use it:

In code behind:

```
ExTest.ModifyControl(Me.Page)
```

New class with various methods in:

```
Public Class ExTest
    Public Shared Sub ModifyControl(aPage As System.Web.UI.Page)
        Dim tb As TextBox = CType(aPage.FindControl("txthelloWorld"), TextBox)
        tb.Text = "Hello World"
    End Sub
End Class
```

2) Extend the code behind as a partial class:

Current code behind (add the Partial keyword):

```
Partial Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ModifyControl()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Add a New class:

```
Partial Public Class WebForm1
    Private Sub ModifyControl()
        txtGoodbyeWorld.Text = "Goodbye"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: hi - thanks for the reply. number 2 is already what i have... what i would like to do is take all those subs (around 3000 lines of code) out of my code behind and put some or all of it in a separate function.vb file for easier management. is that a better explanation of my problem? thanks again.

Comment: wait a minute! i can make as many partial classes as I like right? and divide the functions up in those...

Comment: Yes that's the point. Partial classes (of the same name) just get compiled together as if they were all one class.